# Is there any certain order in the elements of a set definition?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

My professor has defined an equivalence class in modular arithmetic lecture like this:

$\bar{a} = \{b \in \mathbb{Z} \mid b\sim a\} = \{ a + kp \mid k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

I usually face with the set definitions in the following form:

$\{ k \in \mathbb{Z} \mid a + kp \}$

Are both okay, or is there any formal order to define a set? Thanks.

Comment: The first two are acceptable notation.  The third in my experience is not.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate

Comment: I agree with @JMoravitz's comment. Note that none of these notations are *intrinsically* right or wrong. But according to notational conventions that have come to be accepted by the mathematical community, the third notation is unstandard enough to be actively confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I suppose you mean equivalence modulo $p$. Now, if you want to use the first notation
$$
\{b \in {\Bbb Z} \mid b \sim a\}
$$
you first need to define $\sim$. Thus I would prefer
$$
\{ b \in {\Bbb Z} \mid b \equiv a \bmod p\}
$$
The second version, $$\{a + kp \mid k \in{\Bbb Z}\}$$ is correct.
The third one, $\{k \in {\Bbb Z} \mid a +kp \}$ simply does not make sense, as it does not define a set.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: You're welcome.